# JUnit Reports Merger karate

Tags: karate, junit5

Is there a way or feature in karate to combine all the executed reports to merge into one final html report.

We have to rerun failed tests multiple times un till all tests passed and wanted to combined all into one report :

This is not to rerun failed one but to combine previously passed and later rerun of failed scenarios after changes to make it pass.

[image]

Comment: all available options are in linked answer, if you need more, do consider contributing code